# Return the currently logged on domain using Autohotkey

Tags: windows, domain, autohotkey, windows-domain

I am writing a script and want to check whether the user is currently logged into the local machine or to the windows domain.  I specifically want to get the name of the domain, as the script may be used on multiple domains and multiple workstations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use the [Registry Functions](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopReg.htm) on 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Domain` to grab the name.

Comment: Perfect!  One caveat:  the registry value for Domain is empty if logged on to the local machine, so I just had to check for that case and use the built-in A_ComputerName variable.